# Using $timeout-Mock in AngularJS with delay

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angularjs

I've used `$timeout` with a delay of e.g. 600ms in some service code. In the according test I want to assert that the code really does what it is expected to do after the given 600 ms. Is there any way to progress in time with a certain amount of time (similar to `jasmine.Clock.tick(600)`)? I only know about `$timeout.flush()`, but that fires everything currently in the $timeout-queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In AngularJS version 1.2 you can do `$timeout.flush(600)`, which is analogous to Jasmine's `jasmine.Clock.tick(600)`.

In addition to that Angular 1.2 provides a very handy `$timeout.flushNext(msec)` method. It differs from the `flush(msec)` in that that instead of simply putting a clock given time ahead for you to then check if an expected thing happened or not, the `flushNext()` method does both tasks at once. It puts a clock ahead up until the next deferred event is fired and then verifies that the elapsed time equals the given one.

[Link to the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24timeout)

Comment: Good to see that this is added for version 1.2. It doesn't help us though, as we are currently stuck to version 1.0. Nevertheless thanks for pointing out that this feature will be available.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this is present on [1.2.0](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ngMock.$timeout), but gone from [1.2.1](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ngMock.$timeout) onwards.

Comment: AFAICT, the `flushNext` function seems to be gone, but the `flush` function is still there.